# como criar uma tabela para exibir um array

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho o Seguinte Código

```
function imprimirArray(id, array) {
      let span = document.getElementById(id);
      span.innerHTML = '';

      for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        span.innerHTML +=  'pontuação: ' + array[i].soma + ', Categoria: ' + array[i].categoria + ' <br/>';
      }
    }
```

porém quero que ao invés de exibir os dados um ao lado do outro seja em tabela

Comment: Podes mostrar um exemplo da estrutura dessa array?

Comment: se conhece a estrutura de uma `table`, pra cada interação do `for` tem de gerar uma linha `tr` e um `td` para cada propriedade, só mudar isso e sua tabela estará pronta

Answer (score 1):

Para gerar uma tabela com dados dinâmicos um exemplo mínimo foi criado:

```js
const arr = [
  {soma: 100, categoria: "cat1"},
  {soma: 200, categoria: "cat2"},
  {soma: 300, categoria: "cat3"}
];

function imprimirArray(id, array) {
  var table = document.getElementById(id);
  if (table) {
      for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
          var row = table.insertRow(i); // cria a linha
          var cell1 = row.insertCell(0); // cria uma célula na linha
          var cell2 = row.insertCell(1); // cria a outra célula na linha
          cell1.innerHTML = array[i].soma; // na célula passa o valor 
          cell2.innerHTML = array[i].categoria; // na célula passa o valor
      }
  }
}
imprimirArray('table1', arr);
```

```html
<table id="table1" border="1" width="100%">
</table>
```

***Como funciona?***

Busca o `id` da `<table/>` e crie com o comando `insertRow` uma linha na sua tabela, como visto no seu código tem dois campos crie duas células nessa linha com o comando `insertCell` passando o número índice dessas células. Com essas duas celulas adicione pela propriedade `innerHTML` o valor das informações sendo suficiente para mostrar os valores em uma tabela.

<sup>***Referencia:*** [Table insertRow() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_table_insertrow.asp)</sup>